# TIme golang Telegram Bot

Tags: go, time, bots, telegram

I have a telegram bot that helps users to notify if they late for work. So they write as I will come at 12:00 and I get string I have to check if the time they wrote is permitted.

For Example: If they write to me I will come at 12:00 but `time.Now()` is 11:00 so I give them error

The problem is how to compare their local time with time which they sent via bot if they located around the world and my bot server tunning in another country
How to get their local time?

I have 2 solution

> 1. Get user location via IP, GPS
> 2. use if, case statement

Do u have any other idea? I will grateful if u help me.

Code snippet to compare with my local time

```
func getArrivalTime(text string, status string) (time.Time, error) {
    var arrivalTime time.Time
    rule := regexp.MustCompile(`([0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3])((\:)|(\.))[0-5][0-9]`)
    timeStr := rule.FindStringSubmatch(text)
if len(timeStr) == 0 {
    log.Println("ERROR OCCURED")
    return time.Time{}, errors.New("Wrong time format or omitted")
}
timeFormatted := strings.Replace(timeStr[0], ".", ":", 1)
date := fmt.Sprintf("%vT%v:00+00:00", time.Now().Format("2006-01-02"), timeFormatted)
arrivalTime, err := time.Parse(time.RFC3339, date)
if strings.Contains(text, "/завтра") && status == "late" {
    arrivalTime = arrivalTime.Add(time.Hour * 24)
}
arrivalTimeUtc, _ := ConvertToUTC(arrivalTime)

nowUtc, _ := ConvertToUTC(time.Now())
nowUtc = nowUtc.Add(time.Hour * 5)

if arrivalTimeUtc.After(nowUtc) == false && status != "lateButInOffice" {
    log.Println("ERROR OCCURED")
    return time.Time{}, errors.New("Wrong time format or omitted")
}

if err != nil {
    log.Println(err)
}
return arrivalTime, err
}
```

Comment: Generally timestamps sent from client are localised to their timezones already. Is it really necessary to try and figure out the time zone?